# How to reload embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot in runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I change default port of my Spring Boot app by changing server.port property in application.properties file.

But now I need to change this port after the app is started. Is it possible?

Comment: See [Spring Cloud config](https://jeroenbellen.com/manage-and-reload-spring-application-properties-on-the-fly/) - it supports reloading configuration at run time. It may well do exactly what you want, or you may need to do some hackery.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to change the listening port at runtime. You need to restart the application.

Comment: You can stop and restart the embedded server. "_it is not possible_" is too strong. Perhaps "it is not easily possible" or "not possible without custom code".